# Find key of object for deep duplicate values using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I've the following object:

```
var data = {
        2: [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]],
        3: [[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]],
        4: [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]],
        5: [[10,2],[3,4,5],[60,7]]
    }
```

I want the key `2` from the object because its value is duplicate in the array. There may be multiple duplicate keys like this.

I'm using lodash and  tried the following but it wont work. Idon't having idea that how to start:

```
var dups = [];
_.map(formData,function(key, value){
    dups.push(value);
})
var duplicateArray = _.uniqWith(dups, _.isEqual);
```

Comment: Yes I tried uniqBy but how it will provide the key of object? uniqBy works only for arrays not objects

Comment: As far as I know...uniqwith,uniq,uniqBy returns new duplicate free array....U want the duplicates of the parent array whatever depth may be..right?

Comment: I want the keys of the object whose values are existing duplicates with respect to other keys values

Comment: The value of key 2 is coming twice in the entire object. So I want 2 in a separate array

Comment: I dont think lodash would be of much use for your req....given the object structure is way too deep....so better try it yourself with some optimal logic

Comment: I am confused why 2 is coming twice in the entire object? Does 3 meet your requirement?

Comment: Does sequence matter? i.e. is [1,2] same as [2,1] ? and [1,2] same as [1,2,2] ? when I say `same as` I mean semantically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code will match whole array irrespective of value sequence and value count. Consider following example

// Code goes here

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6jEByZHQhcwUopqqG4a2?p=preview
(Click above link and open up console to see the result)

This will output ["2","3"] because "2" `matches` "4" and "3" `matches` "6".

// Code goes here

```
var data = {
  2: [ [1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]],
  3: [[1, 2],[3, 4],[6, 7]],
  4: [[2, 1, 2, 1],[5, 3, 4],[6, 7]],
  5: [[10, 2],[3, 4, 5],[60, 7]],
  6: [[2, 1],[3, 4],[7, 6, 6]]
}

var dups = [];

//sorted and uniq buffer.
var buff = _.clone(data);
_.forEach(buff, function(lvl1, key) {
  buff[key] = _.map(lvl1, function(val) {
    return _.uniq(_.sortBy(val));
  });
});

_.forEach(buff, function(lvl1, key) {

  //Match each row with all others.
  //i.e. 2 with 3, 2 with 4, 2 with 5 ..... 6 with 5.
  _.forEach(buff, function(_lvl1, _key) {
    //Skip entries like 2 with 2, 3 with 3 and so on
    if (key !== _key) {
      console.log('compare ' + key + ' with ' + _key);
      var x = _.filter(_lvl1, function(val, index) {
        //Below condition are only true because ary are sorted and uniq.
              //If both must be of same len 
        return val.length === lvl1[index].length
               //If lenght of intersection of both values must be exactly equal 
               && _.intersection(val, lvl1[index]).length === val.length;
      });
      //If count matches and key and _key is not in dups
      // key and _key not in dups because we only want following:
      // 2 with 4 -> 2
      // 4 with 2 -> ignore! (we dont wanna include 4)
      //Hope it makes sense
      if (x.length === _lvl1.length && _.indexOf(dups, key) === -1 && _.indexOf(dups, _key) === -1) {
         //Mark the key as duplicate
         dups.push(key);
      }
    }

  });
});


console.log(dups)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Dave, Its working fantastic but can you please let me know that how to sort the main object by keys in descending order?

Comment: So instead of ["2","3"], what output you want ["3", "2"] or you want ["6","4"] ?

Comment: Yes I just wanted that. I've done it by replacing dups.push(key); with dups.push(_key);

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that correct understand what you want, but as I assume answer will be look like that way ([sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/eHWJCZFx6faRZWOtkpEj?p=preview)):

**Javascript:**

```
  var data = {
        2: [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]],
        3: [[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]],
        4: [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]],
        5: [[10,2],[3,4,5],[60,7]]
    };

  var find = function(input){
    var res = [];
    for(var prop in input){

      var start = false;
      for(var prop2 in input){
        if(start){
          var flag = JSON.stringify(input[prop]) == JSON.stringify(input[prop2]);
          if(flag){
            var flag3 = true;
            for(var j = 0; j < res.length; j++)
              if(JSON.stringify(input[prop]) == JSON.stringify(input[res[j]])){
                  flag3 = false
                  break;
              }
            if(flag3)
              res.push(prop);
            break;
          }
        }
        else{
         if(prop == prop2)
          start = true; 
        }
      }

    }
    return res;
  }

  var answer = find(data);
```